# Shadow DOM on textarea in iOS forces padding

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari, shadow-dom

I am experiencing an issue which puzzles me a bit.

My reference for this issue is Chrome 32 on Mac and Safari on iOS 7.0.4.

In the following example, Chrome renders the text in the `.background` and `textarea` elements perfect and on top of each other, this is what I want. Safari on iOS though, offsets the text in the `textarea` with 3 pixel-units. This happens although padding, border and margin are set to the same values on both elements.

When I am debugging in Safari's developer tools, both through my iPhone device and the iOS simulator, the elements themselves align perfectly when outlining the elements metrics.

[image: Metrics outline on iOS]

**Markup**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="background">This is a test</div>
    <textarea>This is a test</textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 24px 0;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #f00;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8S5E/2/

Can anyone offer a solution or some theories to research into, for this issue?

**Edit**

It appears that this is an issue with the `textarea`'s shadow DOM node. Does anyone have some reference to how the padding of this element is defined? Percentage value or hard 3px value? Any way to remove this padding?

[image: Shadow DOM node forces padding in textarea]

Comment: Have a look at the related discussion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890149/remove-3-pixels-in-ios-webkit-textarea.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I don't think you can't style inside of the Shadow DOM in iOS. Some elements expose pseudo attributes which you can hook on to. For instance, `<input type="range">` exposes a `-webkit-slider-runnable-track` pseudo element.

http://codepen.io/robdodson/pen/FwlGz

You can see this in the dev tools.

[image]

But I don't think `textarea` exposes such a thing.

Comment: No, it doesn't appear so. I'm not sure if this should be considered a bug in Mobile Safari?

Comment: I guess it would be nice if they exposed a pseudo attribute. Not sure why they have chosen not to. It might be an oversight or it might be for security reasons.

Comment: Agree. It just doesn't seem right how this works. Why is that padding there?