# How do you use window.postMessage across domains?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, xss, postmessage

It seems like the point of [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) is to allow safe communication between windows/frames hosted on different domains, but it doesn't actually seem to *allow* that in Chrome.

Here's the scenario:

1. Embed an <iframe> (with a `src` on domain B<sup>*</sup>) in a page on domain A
2. The <iframe> ends up being mostly a <script> tag, at the end of which's execution...
3. I call window.postMessage( *some_data*, *page_on_A* )

The <iframe> is most definitely in the context of domain B, and I've confirmed that the embedded javascript in that <iframe> executes properly and calls `postMessage` with the correct values.

I get this error message in Chrome:

> Unable to post message to *A*.
>   Recipient has origin *B*.

Here's the code that registers a message event listener in the page on A:

```
window.addEventListener(
  "message",
  function (event) {
    // Do something
  },
  false);
```

I've also tried calling `window.postMessage(some_data, '*')`, but all that does is suppress the error.

Am I just missing the point here, is window.postMessage(...) not meant for this?  Or am I just doing it horribly wrong?

<sub>*Mime-type text/html, which it must remain.</sub>

Comment: You are probably aware of this already, but MDC has an excellent rundown on postMessage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage For the FF implementation obviously, but maybe there's something there that explains why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Here is an example that works on Chrome 5.0.375.125.

The page B (iframe content):

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            top.postMessage('hello', 'A');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note the use of `top.postMessage` or `parent.postMessage` not `window.postMessage` here

The page A:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <iframe src="B"></iframe>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener( "message",
          function (e) {
                if(e.origin !== 'B'){ return; }
                alert(e.data);
          },
          false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

A and B must be something like `http://domain.example`

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411762), it looks the domains(A and B here) must have a `/` for the `postMessage` to work properly.

Comment: When page A checks the origin of the message, the origin will NOT contain a trailing '/'. It does not seem to matter if page B specifies a trailing '/' or not. The other thing to note is that the URLs should be absolute URLs.

Comment: This answer left me a bit confused and still searching for an answer.  http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage contains a very good explanation of the postMessage.  What is important is that the message sender know the domain of the receiver.  In the example above, A and B do not have to be the same domains, but B must know exactly what domain is used by A.

Comment: The question is about cross-domain. The accepted answer is about the same domain.

Comment: @stackular, not exactly. A and B can be any domain. That is the main reason of having `postMessage`

Comment: @Mic Yes, after reading the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage, I saw you were correct.

Comment: `var targetOriginurl = window.document.referrer;
top.`[postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)`('Message', targetOriginurl+'/A');`

to complete my work, for IE used [attachEvent()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657182/correct-usage-of-addeventlistener-attachevent/10896968#10896968) and to get [domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser/20746566#20746566) refered these links

Comment: +1. We want to confirm that this solution worked on our case. We have a page that contains an iframe **from different domain**. Please be note that this only work in Chrome browser, as in firefox we need to use **window.parent.postMessage** instead of **top**. Though we don't know if this can be applied to any other browser.

Answer (score 31):

You should post a message from frame to parent, after loaded.

frame script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.parent.postMessage("I'm loaded", "*");
});
```

And listen it in parent:

```
function listenMessage(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("message", listenMessage, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", listenMessage);
}
```

Use this link for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Messaging

Answer (score 1):

Probably you try to send your data from `mydomain.example` to `www.mydomain.example` or reverse, NOTE you missed "www". `http://mydomain.example` and `http://www.mydomain.example` are different domains to JavaScript.

Comment: In a project I'm doing, I'm using `file:///`  Is it possible to get domain errors when pulling content solely from the local file system?