# Allow iframe links to target parent frames cross domain

Tags: javascript, html, security

I have 2 domains. One page on domain1 uses an iframe to load content from domain2. How do I allow links from domain2 (inside the iframe) open in the full parent frame on domain1?

I've been looking at IEs [application attribute](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=CMfjTfuJMZCp8AOT1tTxBg&usg=AFQjCNGsMK8fq2Erfvg1MH45u62jKUHi_A&sig2=fXaS8ntSnxgeZRyZPgPGgA) and w3c's new [sandbox attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/iframe.html) but I'm unsure how to implement these and if they're compatible cross browser. has anyone any other tricks to get around this?

Is there something I can do with a javascript pixel maybe?

Comment: Have you tried `target="_parent"` on the links in the iframe.

Comment: Yes, the page loads in a new window and chrome throws an error: `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate a navigation change`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**postMessage()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) for sending data across domains.

**1. Code up the links on domain2.com (the links inside the iframe):**

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="top.postMessage('newpage.html','http://domain2.com')"></a>
```

**2. Catch the message in the head of the page on domain1.com (the parent page) and navigate:**

```
window.addEventListener( "message", function(e){
    window.location.href = e.data  //navigates to newpage.html
}, false)
```

Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457391/how-do-you-use-window-postmessage-across-domains) if you need more detais. For < IE8 and other old browsers, there are some hacky workarounds [on this page](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) which look quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javascript to override the A tags and point them to the window.parent.

http://jfcoder.com/test/iframe_open.html

```
window.onload = function(){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i]['_href'] = a[i].href;
        a[i].href = '#';
        a[i].onclick = function(){
            window.parent.location = this._href;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is not the code you'd necessarily want to use in your final code, just a proof of concept. But this works in IE9, FF4 and Chrome (current) without any issues.

Comment: Is this the same as `<a href='#' onclick='window.parent.location="http://www.google.com/";return(false);'>click</a>` ? Because this throws a security error too.