# Navigate between different domains in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe that loads a website, then I have another button to be redirected to another site (with different domain). But, I am not getting what I want, when I click on the redirection button I just get a link:

```
<iframe src="https://FirstSite.com/">
   #document
   <html>
       <a href="http://SecondSite.com">Found</a>.
   </html>
</iframe>
```

So, as you see, the second site is not being rendered. It's only creating a link (that doesnt even work, if I click it then it does nothing!)

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178728/allow-iframe-links-to-target-parent-frames-cross-domain

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand... This is what I got...

```html
<iframe src="https://FirstSite.com/" name="myFrame"></iframe>
    <p><a href="http://SecondSite.com" target="myFrame">Found</a></p>
```