# javascript postMessage not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I don't know what to do. I tried several sample codes from different sources, I tried them in different browsers (from Chrome 9 to FF 4), and still nothing seems to be working with the "postMessage" function.
JS console is giving me nothing, not a single error, still nothing is happening : the frames don't want to communicate. At all. And this isn't even cross-domain : both frames are from my domain.

Here is a sample code from the last try :
Parent frame :

```
<iframe src="IFRAME_URL"></iframe>
<script>
    window.addEventListener( "message",
      function (e) {
            if(e.origin !== 'DOMAIN'){ return; } 
            alert(e.data);
      },
      false);
</script>
```

Child frame :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        top.postMessage('hello', 'DOMAIN');
    </script>
</body>
```

Help much appreciated, thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have only 2 levels in your iframe? May be `top` is not where your listener is declared. May be try with `parent.postMessage`.

Comment: tried with parent.postMessage, still not working

Comment: Did you try my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457391 ?

Comment: ok I got it working............... apparently DOMAIN must not end with a slash. sigh.

Comment: ah... I just tried with a real url, and it worked fine. Probably must have a `/` yes :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The second parameter of your `postMessage` must be an url like `http://localhost`

Comment: Alternatively, the parameter can be `"*"`... which I **highly** discourage for anything but testing purposes.

Answer (score 5):

you can also send the message to any window use `top.postMessage('hello', "*");`

Html 1:

```
<iframe src="IFRAME_URL"></iframe>
<script>
window.addEventListener( "message",
  function (e) { 
        alert(e.data);
  },
  false);
</script>
```

html 2:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        top.postMessage('hello', '*');
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are not dealing with different origins, entering `location.origin` as the *[targetOrigin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)* will work.

```
top.postMessage('hello', location.origin);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the security concerns, but typically, I just grab the parent window location like this:

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location;
top.postMessage('message', url);
```

Comment: The result is that everyone who includes your iframe in his page, will receive the messages. Afaik it's as unsafe as using "*" for the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the execute order of `addEventListner` and `postMessage` is correct.

Try add `setTimeout(fn, 0)` to `postMessage`:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  top.postMessage('hello', 'DOMAIN');
}, 0)
```

This solved my issue after 2 hours investigation.