# Global Variable in jQuery Mobile not working anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, global

I changed my website into a mobile website by using the jQuery Mobile framework. To save and overwrite variables to another site, I use a frame and declare the variable like `top.variable = "...";`.

This was a working for me, but now I use jQuery Mobile it doesn`t keep the variable, it only stops the function.

```
<form id="login">
    <input href="#" name="name"  id="name" type="text"/>
</form>

<a href="#" id="next" class="ui-disabled" data-role="button" onclick="next()">Send</a>
```

```js
function next() {   
    top.username = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("nextSite").submit();
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: where is `nextSite` here????

Comment: Hello, 'nextSite' is the id to my next html-site.

Comment: Not 100% sure but dont you need (var top = '';) at the top of your function. It doesnt look like you are declaring a variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Why don't you try this?

- [Access a variable of iframe from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757943/access-a-variable-of-iframe-from-parent)

`top.username=document.getElementById("iframeid").contentDocument.top.username;`