# How to access an iframe from the including document object

Tags: javascript, html, pdftron

I have a pdftron webviewer and I am trying to access it outside the [config.js](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/tutorials/getting-started-config-files.html). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37331722/3804420) suggests to access iframe variables through `contentWindow` and get hold of `readerControl`.

But the problem is the `iframe` created by PDFTron WebViewer has a random id attribute. in order for us to confidently use it, we nee to set the `id` or `class` of the iframe to what we know of. I am trying to access the enclosing `iframe` using the `document` object which is inside it. I have found the solutions on how to access the other way around.

```
$(document).parents()
```

is null

My HTML

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <iframe id="random_number">
  #document
 </iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: How many IFrames you have in your document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe can confidently be grabed by selecting within the viewer element. All you need is the id of the element you provided when instantiating WebViewer

`<div id="viewer"></div>`

```
$(function() {
    var viewerElement = document.getElementById("viewer");
    var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
        path: "lib",
        type: "html5",
        initialDoc: "GettingStarted.xod"
    }, viewerElement);
});
```

`var iframe = document.querySelector('#viewer iframe')`