# How to access the json variable which is inside the script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

How to access the variable which is inside the script tag (Script considered as string).

I will get this content with this content i have to access this varible `ad_json`

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].contentDocument.querySelectorAll('script')[1].outerHTML)
```

It will output the String

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function populate(el) { var adBlock = document.getElementById("adBlock");adBlock.innerHTML += el;}
        var caps_ = {
"clicktracking": true, "customAdIcons": true, "isLtr": true, "isRtl": false, "isDesktop": true
};
        var IS_GOOGLE_AFS_IFRAME_ = true;
        var ad_json = {
          "ads": [],
          "ias": [],
          "rss": [{
            "t": "Crossover Vehicles",
            "tr": {
              "c": "Crossover Vehicles",
              "rtl": false
            },
            "afdt": "CpECChMIyPq38qfP1QIVUIpoCh3YFwx5GAEgAFDtrdAJULSu0AlQsa_QCVC4r9AJUMqv0AlQjrDQCVCesNAJUKew0AlQqLDQCVCpsNAJULKw0AlQtLDQCVC1sNAJULew0AlQuLDQCVC7sNAJUL2w0AlQwrDQCVDDsNAJUMSw0AlQxrDQCVDKsNAJUM2w0AlQ0bDQCVDTsNAJUNew0AlQ6qjRClDrzMcMUO-c5RFQ6LyoE1D70MEsUPv9yTVQ95D4OVD1su6XAVCoq_SxAVC2ycWzAVCm87COAlChxbHZAlDR1cD7AnFzram4RtNPKYIBEwihm7jyp8_VAhWKpGgKHU84BAaNAafQqOyRASXTH-N91-AHEhkAbTqKkE4-VScYvnqlFNlUs05lIpYTIMy7",
            "fn": "slave-0",
            "sls": []},{
            "t": "Crossover SUV",
            "tr": {
              "c": "Crossover SUV",
              "rtl": false
            },
            "afdt": "CpECChMIyPq38qfP1QIVUIpoCh3YFwx5GAEgAVDtrdAJULSu0AlQsa_QCVC4r9AJUMqv0AlQjrDQCVCesNAJUKew0AlQqLDQCVCpsNAJULKw0AlQtLDQCVC1sNAJULew0AlQuLDQCVC7sNAJUL2w0AlQwrDQCVDDsNAJUMSw0AlQxrDQCVDKsNAJUM2w0AlQ0bDQCVDTsNAJUNew0AlQ6qjRClDrzMcMUO-c5RFQ6LyoE1D70MEsUPv9yTVQ95D4OVD1su6XAVCoq_SxAVC2ycWzAVCm87COAlChxbHZAlDR1cD7AnFzram4RtNPKYIBEwihm7jyp8_VAhWKpGgKHU84BAaNAUwFWeiRASXTH-N91-AHEhkAbTqKkLA6p3f0s6oWGbqSRGWBz9IMpH3w",
            "fn": "slave-0",
            "sls": []},{
            "t": "Cross over Vehicle",
            "tr": {
              "c": "Cross over Vehicle",
              "rtl": false
            },
            "afdt": "CpECChMIyPq38qfP1QIVUIpoCh3YFwx5GAEgAlDtrdAJULSu0AlQsa_QCVC4r9AJUMqv0AlQjrDQCVCesNAJUKew0AlQqLDQCVCpsNAJULKw0AlQtLDQCVC1sNAJULew0AlQuLDQCVC7sNAJUL2w0AlQwrDQCVDDsNAJUMSw0AlQxrDQCVDKsNAJUM2w0AlQ0bDQCVDTsNAJUNew0AlQ6qjRClDrzMcMUO-c5RFQ6LyoE1D70MEsUPv9yTVQ95D4OVD1su6XAVCoq_SxAVC2ycWzAVCm87COAlChxbHZAlDR1cD7AnFzram4RtNPKYIBEwihm7jyp8_VAhWKpGgKHU84BAaNAV29F-WRASXTH-N91-AHEhkAbTqKkENkB4HSdl0GsagRpK2rY8hGuQWV",
            "fn": "slave-0",
            "sls": []},{
            "t": "Best Crossover",
            "tr": {
              "c": "Best Crossover",
              "rtl": false
            },
            "afdt": "CpECChMIyPq38qfP1QIVUIpoCh3YFwx5GAEgA1DtrdAJULSu0AlQsa_QCVC4r9AJUMqv0AlQjrDQCVCesNAJUKew0AlQqLDQCVCpsNAJULKw0AlQtLDQCVC1sNAJULew0AlQuLDQCVC7sNAJUL2w0AlQwrDQCVDDsNAJUMSw0AlQxrDQCVDKsNAJUM2w0AlQ0bDQCVDTsNAJUNew0AlQ6qjRClDrzMcMUO-c5RFQ6LyoE1D70MEsUPv9yTVQ95D4OVD1su6XAVCoq_SxAVC2ycWzAVCm87COAlChxbHZAlDR1cD7AnFzram4RtNPKYIBEwihm7jyp8_VAhWKpGgKHU84BAaNAYmlWm-RASXTH-N91-AHEhkAbTqKkA2DzXXg5M1ahVaNg45HmdPJouvl",
            "fn": "slave-0",
            "sls": []},{
            "t": "AWD Crossovers",
            "tr": {
              "c": "AWD Crossovers",
              "rtl": false
            },
            "afdt": "CpECChMIyPq38qfP1QIVUIpoCh3YFwx5GAEgBFDtrdAJULSu0AlQsa_QCVC4r9AJUMqv0AlQjrDQCVCesNAJUKew0AlQqLDQCVCpsNAJULKw0AlQtLDQCVC1sNAJULew0AlQuLDQCVC7sNAJUL2w0AlQwrDQCVDDsNAJUMSw0AlQxrDQCVDKsNAJUM2w0AlQ0bDQCVDTsNAJUNew0AlQ6qjRClDrzMcMUO-c5RFQ6LyoE1D70MEsUPv9yTVQ95D4OVD1su6XAVCoq_SxAVC2ycWzAVCm87COAlChxbHZAlDR1cD7AnFzram4RtNPKYIBEwihm7jyp8_VAhWKpGgKHU84BAaNAWyi6KORASXTH-N91-AHEhkAbTqKkEcjuf9cx8bN0AZVTs0PNCVoIyxQ",
            "fn": "slave-0",
            "sls": []},{
            "t": "Compare Luxury Cars",
            "tr": {
              "c": "Compare Luxury Cars",
              "rtl": false
            },
            "afdt": "CpECChMIyPq38qfP1QIVUIpoCh3YFwx5GAEgBVDtrdAJULSu0AlQsa_QCVC4r9AJUMqv0AlQjrDQCVCesNAJUKew0AlQqLDQCVCpsNAJULKw0AlQtLDQCVC1sNAJULew0AlQuLDQCVC7sNAJUL2w0AlQwrDQCVDDsNAJUMSw0AlQxrDQCVDKsNAJUM2w0AlQ0bDQCVDTsNAJUNew0AlQ6qjRClDrzMcMUO-c5RFQ6LyoE1D70MEsUPv9yTVQ95D4OVD1su6XAVCoq_SxAVC2ycWzAVCm87COAlChxbHZAlDR1cD7AnFzram4RtNPKYIBEwihm7jyp8_VAhWKpGgKHU84BAaNAWMpD6CRASXTH-N91-AHEhkAbTqKkCRn1yPsJQ5Y7wZcHmxdz3jorS0w",
            "fn": "slave-0",
            "sls": []},{
            "t": "Mid Size Luxury Cars",
            "tr": {
              "c": "Mid Size Luxury Cars",
              "rtl": false
            },
            "afdt": "CpECChMIyPq38qfP1QIVUIpoCh3YFwx5GAEgBlDtrdAJULSu0AlQsa_QCVC4r9AJUMqv0AlQjrDQCVCesNAJUKew0AlQqLDQCVCpsNAJULKw0AlQtLDQCVC1sNAJULew0AlQuLDQCVC7sNAJUL2w0AlQwrDQCVDDsNAJUMSw0AlQxrDQCVDKsNAJUM2w0AlQ0bDQCVDTsNAJUNew0AlQ6qjRClDrzMcMUO-c5RFQ6LyoE1D70MEsUPv9yTVQ95D4OVD1su6XAVCoq_SxAVC2ycWzAVCm87COAlChxbHZAlDR1cD7AnFzram4RtNPKYIBEwihm7jyp8_VAhWKpGgKHU84BAaNAZZA-FCRASXTH-N91-AHEhkAbTqKkJMEmTodIn7fE9H36fnSp-Q5BPbZ",
            "fn": "slave-0",
            "sls": []},{
            "t": "Top 10 Best Cars",
            "tr": {
              "c": "Top 10 Best Cars",
              "rtl": false
            },
            "afdt": "CpECChMIyPq38qfP1QIVUIpoCh3YFwx5GAEgB1DtrdAJULSu0AlQsa_QCVC4r9AJUMqv0AlQjrDQCVCesNAJUKew0AlQqLDQCVCpsNAJULKw0AlQtLDQCVC1sNAJULew0AlQuLDQCVC7sNAJUL2w0AlQwrDQCVDDsNAJUMSw0AlQxrDQCVDKsNAJUM2w0AlQ0bDQCVDTsNAJUNew0AlQ6qjRClDrzMcMUO-c5RFQ6LyoE1D70MEsUPv9yTVQ95D4OVD1su6XAVCoq_SxAVC2ycWzAVCm87COAlChxbHZAlDR1cD7AnFzram4RtNPKYIBEwihm7jyp8_VAhWKpGgKHU84BAaNAX8d3WGRASXTH-N91-AHEhkAbTqKkBDenlZUpnknf5QoiNQMdwbtFUIt",
            "fn": "slave-0",
            "sls": []}],
          "sbs": [],
          "attr":{"t":"Sponsored Listings","u":"https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/request.py?contact=abg_afc&url=http://crossovercarstoday.sale/&hl=en&client=dp-dotzup20_3ph_js&gl=IN",
            "alt_t":{
              "Ads":"Ads",
              "Sponsored Listings":"Sponsored Listings"
            }
          },
          "rs_attr":{"t":"Related Links","u":"https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/request.py?contact=abg_afc&url=http://crossovercarstoday.sale/&hl=en&client=dp-dotzup20_3ph_js&gl=IN"}
        };
        var status_ = {
          "feed": "afc"
        };
      </script>
```

I don't how to parse this as a javascript content and get the varible

Comment: This is in an iframe? Is the domain of the iframe the same as the outer page? If they're different domains, you may not be able to access its contents.

Comment: i've disabled the web security for developent

Comment: You may want to check out [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757943/access-a-variable-of-iframe-from-parent).

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein it is not working for me

Comment: What errors or output are you getting? Can you show all relevant HTML and code?