# Can bookmarket modify original page?

Tags: bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that opens a dialog (in reality an iframe) and extracts some information. When the dialog is dismissed I want to put that information into edit text fields  on the original page in the browser (like the way LastPass will automatically fill-in login forms on a page).

Is this possible? I'm thinking that same-origin-policy will prevent this, but maybe there is a way (without installing extensions such as greasemonkey, etc).

**Edit**: to be more precise: the bookmarklet appends a DIV to the original page; that DIV contains an IFRAME that loads my page; this page fetches some information; once this information is fetched within the IFRAME I want to remove the DIV and (somehow) put that information into the original page.

The issue I face is communicating the information in the IFRAME back to the original page.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are the functions addEventListener and postMessage.

Relevant links:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging

[How do you use window.postMessage across domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457391/how-do-you-use-window-postmessage-across-domains)