# Cookie set to parent window from iframe javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, cookies

please anybody help me to set a cookie on parent window from a iframe in javascript.
if it is possible, please provide some links related.
ex:parent page has domain **ABC.com**

IFRAME on that page pointing to **XYZ.com**, i want to write a script in iframe to drop a cookie on ABC.com, that is on parent page.

Comment: You can not set cookies for different domains. If you want to cookie set for abc.com, then abc.com itself has to set it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use postMessage to post from child window(i.e iFrame) and then listen the event at parent.

```
  window.parent.postMessage("Value", "*");
  window.addEventListener();
```

This post might help you to understand more.
[How do you use window.postMessage across domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457391/how-do-you-use-window-postmessage-across-domains)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you do it.

**iFrame Website**
Paste the below code in the iFrame website:

```
<script>

    /* Sends a hello from the iframe to the parent */    
    parent.postMessage('hello_from_the_iframe', 'https://parentwebsite.com/');

</script>
```

**Parent website**
Paste the below code in the parent website where the iFrame is embedded to set cookie:

```
<script> 

    window.addEventListener("message",function (e) { 

            /*Check if the iframe website is sending the message*/
            if(e.origin === 'https://iframewebsite.com'){ 

                    /*Check if you got a hello from the iframe*/
                    if(e.data === 'hello_from_the_iframe'){

                        /*Function to set Cookie*/
                        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
                            var d = new Date();
                            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
                            var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
                            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
                        }

                        /* Set the cookie 'set_my_cookie'*/
                        setCookie('set_my_cookie',1,365);

                        /* Get notification that the cookie is set*/
                        alert('cookie set');
                    }
            }
    },false);

</script>
```

You need to replace `https://parentwebsite.com/` with the domain of the website where the iframe is embedded.

You also need to replace the `https://iframewebsite.com` with the origin of the iFrame. If you don't know the origin of the iFrame then just paste the below code in the iFrame HTML and it will be shown to you the origin in an alert box.

```
<script>
    alert(window.location.origin);
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: index.js?44d8:27 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:3000') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:3020'). i get this error when i tried your solution

Comment: Not sure why. Are you trying it in local version of the websites or is it hosted in a web server?

Comment: in local so far, i will try it out on web servers and will give you more feedback