# Close iframe within iframe (parent:php, child:aspx) when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, iframe

I have been trying to figure this out for a while and I see many similar questions but not exactly what I'm looking for.

I have a .php page as a parent page, and it has an iFrame which displays a .aspx page. 
What I want to do is: when user clicks a button inside the aspx page, close the modal iframe and go back to the php page.

```
parent.php
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                           |
|                                           |
|       "survey"                            |
|       CloseSurvey()                       |
|       +--------------------------+        |
|       |                          |        |
|       |                          |        |
|       |    child.aspx            |        |
|       |    +---------------+     |        |
|       |    |               |     |        |
|       |    |    btnClose   |     |        |
|       |    |               |     |        |
|       |    |               |     |        |
|       |    |               |     |        |
|       |    +---------------+     |        |
|       |                          |        |
|       |                          |        |
|       +--------------------------+        |
|                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+

void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Close iframe
}
```

I have tried

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "CLOSEWINDOW", "parent.CloseSurvey()");
```

and it didn't do anything. No error, and won't close.

I've been trying to figure out how I can call the method in parent, but I still can't figure it out yet.

How can I close the modal iframe popup from child.aspx??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your php and aspx pages are on the **same** domain, you can do this:

on your PHP page have a public method named `closeIframe`

on click of the close button from the .aspx page, invoke the `closeIframe` method from the parent using `window.parent.closeIframe`

the closeIframe method in the PHP page can either hide or remove the iframe depending on what your requirements are.

if your php and aspx pages are on **different** domains, you can implement similar functionality, but you will need to use [window message events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3457391/1000175).

also, if the close button does not need to invoke any server-side code, I would recommend that you make the close button with an `<a>` tag.

**edit:**

since the aspx page is on a subdomain, then the solution would involve window message events.

*script to invoke from **aspx** on close button click:*

```
window.parent.postMessage("closeframe", "*");
```

*code on **php** page to listen for messages:*

```
function listenMessage(event) {
    switch(event){
        case "closeframe":
            //logic to close the iframe
            break;
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("message", listenMessage, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", listenMessage);
}
```

Comment: the domain is the same but the subdomain is not. (e.g. the parent is `parent.com` and the child is `child.parent.com`). I'll try window message events. Thank you!

Comment: ok, then the window message events should work perfectly for you.

Comment: i edited my answer to help you with the message events

Answer (score 0):

You don't really close an `<iframe>`. You either change the `Element.src` or remove the Element, using either `Element.innerHTML = ''` or `Element.removeChild(otherNode)`. Use `frames[number]` to get the `iframe` from within your .aspx file using JavaScript.