# Click on iframe to make a button appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a pub in iframe, I have a button and I would like to make sure that the user is obliged to click on the ad before the button appears but I can not find how to do it . Thank you for your help

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">

<input id="bouton" type="submit" style="color:black;" name="Envoyer" id="Envoyer" value="SEND"><br/>

<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="90" width="728" src="http://www.website.com/ban.php?id=701&f=728x90"></iframe>

</form>
```

I tried :

```
<div id="pub" style="display:none;">
<input id="bouton" type="submit" style="color:black;" name="Envoyer" id="Envoyer" value="SEND">
</div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('pub').style.display = 'block';"><iframe scrolling="no" id="pub" frameborder="0" height="90" width="728" src="http://www.website.com/ban.php?id=701&f=728x90"></iframe>
</button>
```

EDIT :

I tried with it also but I did not succeed:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
document.getElementById("pub").dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: _"but I can not find how to do it"_, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please may you put the code in the question itself?

Comment: I corrected my subject ^^

Comment: Simple answer you can't unless the content of the `iframe` is on the same domain.

Comment: @kodecount - That'll only work if both pages are in the same domain. "*user is obliged to click on the ad*" suggests that maybe these pages will be hosted from different domains.

Comment: Yes I know that but he won't be able to unless CORS is setup on the other domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use window.postMessage across domains?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457391/how-do-you-use-window-postmessage-across-domains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not easy (for me) but I managed to do what I want to do.
I put the result at the disposal if it will interest somebody in the same situation as me

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="show-comments">Show Comments</button>
<div id="comments">
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="90" width="728" src="www.test.com"></iframe><br/>
<div id="result"><input type="submit" value="SEND"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#result {
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
#comments {
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$("#show-comments").click(function(){
    $("#comments").show();
});

$(window).click(function(e) {
    $('#result').hide();
});

$(window).blur(function(e) {
    $('#result').show();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w0dph6e0/1/