# Check if window popup close or not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am opening a youtube video on popup using javascript. I am using the following code

```
  var myWindow;
    $("#nextview").click(function() {

    var vidurl = 'www.youtube.com'; 
    myWindow = window.open(vidurl, "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
    //counter(myWindow,refreshIntervalId);

});
```

Now I want to show message when user close this popup window.

What I Tried

```
myWindow.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
    event.returnValue = "Write something clever here..";
});
```

Getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
```

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine, check it here https://jsfiddle.net/s254e3bk/1/

Comment: Looks like `addEventListener` is called before `myWindow` is initialized.

Comment: not its after mywindow @MaazSyedAdeeb

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I want to check if user closing the window or not and do some functionality there

Comment: @azadchouhan If you run the code i provided, then it writes to the console log when the user closes the window. If that is not what you want please explain.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes your answer is working. But with the same domain's popup window. In my case the popup window will open a youtube video from my another website. so the url of both windows will be different. this is my problem. What I have to do for it?

Comment: it's only a event about the popup window, not about the URL

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457391/?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var myWindow;
    $("#nextview").click(function() {

    var vidurl = 'www.youtube.com'; 
    myWindow = window.open(vidurl, "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
    //counter(myWindow,refreshIntervalId);
    myWindow.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
       //some code like
       alert("closed");
}
});
```

this also can able to catch the window close.

Comment: my website domain n window popup domain is different. My popup will open a youtube video. this iwll work when the url of both windows are same

Comment: check first and let me know

Comment: I don't know why it is not working but in fiddle its working well

Comment: is there any way to know why onbeforeunload  is not working with https://www.youtube.com ?