# How to listen submit event from popup window to parent page- cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to listen click/submit event from popup window to parent page.
Here below code works if both parent and popup window belongs to same domain say http://localhost (check below commented line in code) but it will not call eventHandler method if popup has different domain say echosign.com.
In below code parent window is localhost or anything other than popup.

```
var newWindow;
function OpenPopup() {
    //newWindow = window.open("http://localhost:21930/Popup.htm", "PopupWindow", "width=300,height=100");
    newWindow = window.open("https://secure.echosign.com", "PopupWindow", "width=300,height=100");
    if (newWindow.addEventListener) {
        newWindow.addEventListener('click', eventHandler, false);
    } else {          
        newWindow.attachEvent('onclick', eventHandler);
    }
}

function eventHandler(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.origin == "https://secure.echosign.com") {
        console.log("Event from Adobe Sign!", JSON.parse(e.data));           
    } else {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.origin);           
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457391/how-do-you-use-window-postmessage-across-domains

Comment: Maarten- your suggested url not helpful to me

Comment: That is part of *"same origin poilicy"* security restrictions

Answer (score 0):

If you have control on both domains you can set the headers to accept the other domain.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
```

Comment: Thanks for reply: I don't have any control on popup window domain. but as security wise we allowed this domain to our project.