# JavaScript Message event not being fired

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, postmessage

I have a simple HTML5 page with an iframe whose src attribute is initially empty string. The page renders without any JavaScript errors.

The `src` attribute of iframe element is only set when the window has loaded, so initially an empty iframe loads. The iframe src is being set to a page from another domain.

The problem I am facing is that the `postMessage` method works without throwing any errors, however the source page is not firing the `message` event even though it's set up before the iframe page starts loading. I am having the alert messages from iframe page show up, which means the postMessage method did not throw any errors.

**Question**

What am I missing when subscribing to the message event in source page?

**Source page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Cross domain iframe messaging</title>
    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var iframec = null;

            window.addEventListener("load", function () {

                iframec = document.getElementById("iframec");

                //set up event listener for iframe object so it can receive message from page shown in iframe
                iframec.contentWindow.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
                    alert("received: " + event.data);
                }, false);

                //load the iframe page but after you have set up to receive messages
                iframec.src = "http://www.abcx.com";
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div>
        <h1>Testing iframe messaging in a Cross Domain scenario</h1>
       <p> Trying to send a message to an iframe that comes from a page in another domain. The postMessage method does not throw an error when called from the other domain page, but it's not being received by the page having iframe element in it.</p>
      <div id="divComments"></div>
        <iframe src=""  id="iframec" name="iframec"  style="border:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%; "></iframe>
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Iframe Page JavaScript that is not throwing any error** (i.e. page at `http://www.abcx.com`)

```
<script>

      $( document ).ready(function() {

          alert("loaded the iframe page on another domain. Just before  postMessage");

          window.postMessage("Some message was sent from other domain message", "*");

          alert("loaded the iframe page on another domain. Just after postMessage");
});

</script>
```

Comment: You've said you're seeing the alerts from the iframe, but the iframe doesn't include jQuery (and relies on jQuery). It doesn't inherit it from the enclosing page. So if you're seeing the alerts, the above is **not** the full content of the page you're loading in the iframe.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, The page at www.abcx.com has jquery included. Also, I have mentioned only the script part of the page at www.abcx.com and not the full html markup of it.

Comment: Okay. Next time, it would be good to include at least enough of the iframe code that it would work when copied and pasted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I normally would have included, but in this case my iframe page had too much of markup, so I omitted the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hooking up the listener on the wrong window, and using the wrong window to send the message. (This is fairly easy to get wrong. :-) )

In the main window, you want to receive `message` events on the main window, not the iframe, so:

```
    window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
//  ^^^^^^^
        alert("received: " + event.data);
    }, false);
```

In the iframe, you want to send to `window.parent` (well, `parent`), not `window`:

```
    parent.postMessage("Some message was sent from other domain message", "*");
//  ^^^^^^
```

With both of those changes, the message sent by the iframe is received by the main window.

Comment: Ok. Let me try it out.

Comment: That worked.Thanks.

Comment: Is `parent.window` from iframe page not pointing to iframe.contentWindow? From the way your code worked, it seems it points to main window of source page.

Comment: @Sunil: (You mean `parent`, not `parent.window`, though `parent.window` works [as does `parent.window.window` and `parent.window.window.window`] because `parent === parent.window`.) In the iframe, `parent` refers to the window that contains it (your main page in this case). You can't do virtually anything with that window other than call `postMessage` on it (because it's from a different origin).

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake and now I cannot edit my comment.

Comment: @Sunil: No worries, we can just delete all the comments above if you're all set now...?

Comment: Yes, I get it now very well. May be these comments might help some future reader.

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457391/how-do-you-use-window-postmessage-across-domains)

On the page you're trying to load, it should be using `top.postMessage` or `parent.postMessage`

Additionally, you should be attaching the listener to the `window`, not the iframe (and make sure to filter the origin, or else localhost will throw you a false positive)

This is the version of yours I was playing with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
        var iframec = null;

        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            if(!iframec){
                iframec = document.getElementById("iframec");

                //set up event listener for iframe object so it can receive message from page shown in iframe
                window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
                    if(event.origin == '[your domain here]') alert("received from " + event.origin + ": " + event.data);
                }, false);

                //load the iframe page but after you have set up to receive messages
                iframec.src = "[iframe target url]";
            }
        });
</script>
```

And the target for the iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
     alert('loaded the page. Just before  postMessage');
     top.postMessage("Some message was sent from appsprocure", "*");
     alert("loaded the page. Just after postMessage");
   });
 </script>
</head>
<body><h1>Hello!</h1></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I liked the use of `top` in your answer since then the topmost window can be accessed.