# Passing & Retriving localStorage value in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

**Background:**

1. In android Webview:

   - Html file saved Locally.
2. When user is Online

   - URL is called and `Page A` is loaded from Website.
   - certain data is stored in `localStorage('X')` on `Page A`.
3. When user is offline

   - Html `Page B` (saved locally) is displayed.
   - `Page B` fetch data from `localStorage('X')` and store in `localStorage('Y')`.
   - `Page B` perform operations on `localStorage('Y')` in JavaScript.
4. When user is Online again

   - Page A fetch data from `localStorage('Y')` and store in `localStorage('X')`.

**Issue**

`localStorage('X')` value is not passed to `localStorage('Y')` & vice-versa.

**Looking for:**

Ways to pass `localStorage` Value from Website to local HTML file & Vice-Versa

Comment: localStorage would require both pages to be on the same domain. If that is not the case, you won't be able to share data between them.

Comment: @NisargShah how to pass this value from one domain to another?

Comment: One of the workarounds would be to use an IFrame inside the locally stored page and PostMessage API. Let me see if there is an answer that explains it, or I will post an answer.

Comment: @NisargShah can you elaborate about PostMessage API? It would be great help if you provide working example

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with WebView, but in principle, the solution in my answer should work well. Try going through the links related to postMessage first. It should be simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share data across two domains using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

One of the methods used to share data across domains is through use of [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API. In addition to the MDN link, you can find some more details here: [How do you use window.postMessage across domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3457391/5894241)

In your case, you may need to make the following changes:

- When user is Online

  - Locally saved `Page C` is opened
  - `Page C` opens Page A in an iframe element.
  - Whenever `Page A` needs to save any data to `localStorage`, it sends the data via `postMessage` to the parent page, i.e. `Page C`. In turn `Page C` can save the data to localStorage.
- When user is offline

  - Html `Page B` (saved locally) is displayed.
  - It can refer to the data in `localStorage` stored by `Page C`, because both were opened offline.