# Desktop Safari ( Mac & Windows ) VS Mobile Safari (iPhone) - HTML, CSS, JS support

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile-safari

Is support of HTML, CSS and Javascript same in Desktop Safari ( Mac & Windows ) and Mobile Safari (iPhone)?

If I'm making some thing for iPhone Safari and use Desktop version Safari on my Windows 7 PC to test and debugging, after fininsh will it look same on both? Are there any difference between Safari ( Desktop ) and Safari (iphone) in terms of support of HTML, CSS and Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006647/list-of-known-safari-on-ipad-differences-over-desktop-safari ipad to desktop comparison though

Comment: @JohnP - Thanks, so the differences between the iphone safari and desktop safari will be the same like ipad differences, right?

Comment: most probably. I can't confirm which is why I haven't posted this as an answer.

Comment: @JohnP - +1 But the link you shared is very good. thanks

Answer (score 4):

They are based on the same html render engine - WebKit. Pure HTML, CSS and Javascript are supported in mobile safari and desktop version. But if you are doing sth in Flash or Applet, mobile safari does not support that. Some HTML5 tags are not fully supported, like File/FileSystem interface. You still need to test the pages in mobile safari, although developing them in desktop version safari in first place is a good way.