# addEventListener useCapture support on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile

It seems that the useCapture flag has a pretty good support on desktop browsers.

In this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener, at the bottom there is a compatibility table, but it's incomplete for mobile.

So my question is: can i use the useCapture flag on those devices: Android, IE Mobile, Opera Mobile, Safari Mobile?

Comment: I could test it on android 5.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research, I concluded that it should work the same on those mobiles.

Chrome works the same on android: [What are differences between Chrome on Android and Desktop Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944522/what-are-differences-between-chrome-on-android-and-desktop-chrome)

Opera browser on android might works the same than the desktop version: http://www.opera.com/blogs/india/2015/05/which-is-the-best-opera-browser-for-android-phones/

For the main part, safari mobile might work the same as safari desktop: [Desktop Safari ( Mac & Windows ) VS Mobile Safari (iPhone) - HTML, CSS, JS support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702832/desktop-safari-mac-windows-vs-mobile-safari-iphone-html-css-js-suppo)

Ie mobile should work like ie11 desktop: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Mobile