# Offscreen div causes window to expand only in mobile browser

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am putting together a site for an anti-bullying program at my school and I am trying to include a fun and animated background. I decided that moving clouds looked sort of cool, so I implemented them into the background. Earlier on, I had this bug where offscreen clouds would stretch the page and add a scrollbar to the bottom of the page going horizontally. I fixed this by making the body div have this css style:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

That solved the problem for desktop browsers, but when I view the site on my iPad and phone it lets me scroll over to the side when the cloud progresses to that point. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is happening? Thank you.

Here is my index.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <title>
        Stop It!
        </title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <div id="env">
            <img class="envimg" id="people" src="peeps.png" alt="people" />
            <img class="envimg" id="school" src="school.png" alt="school" />
        </div>
        <div id="sunmoon">
            <img id="sunmoonimg" src="sun.png" alt="sun" />
        </div>
        <div id="grass"></div>
        <div class="cloud" id="cloud1"><img src="cloud.png" /></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="environment.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my stylesheet:

```
*
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#grass
{
left: 0px;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-image: url(grass.jpg);
bottom:0px;
margin:0px;
position:absolute;
padding:0px;
font-size:15px;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
}

#env
{
z-index: 1;
position:absolute;
height:500px;
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
left:0px;
}

.envimg
{
bottom:0px;
position:absolute;
float:left;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#people
{
right: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -439px;
margin-left: -438px;
z-index:2;
}

#school
{
right: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -300px;
margin-left: -300px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
z-index:1;
}

body, html
{
overflow:hidden;
}

.cloud
{
bottom: 0px;
left: -600px;
position:absolute;
}

#sunmoon
{
position:absolute;
top:100px;
right:200px;
z-index:-1;
height:300px;
}

#sunmoonimg
{
height:300px;
}

#content
{
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:1000px;
margin-top:50px;
background-color:white;
}
```

Here is the javascript file that controls cloud movement and some other stuff:

```
var windowheight = window.innerHeight - 600;
var cloud = document.getElementById("cloud1");
var cloudpos = Math.random() * windowheight;
cloud.style.top = cloudpos + 'px';
cloud.style.left = '-600px';
var cloudx = -600;
var school = document.getElementById("school");
var peeps = document.getElementById("people");
var t = setInterval("movecloud()",1000/60);
var cloudvel = 0.5;
function startCloud()
{
    cloudx = -600;
    cloudpos = Math.random() * windowheight;
}
function movecloud()
{
    cloudx = cloudx + cloudvel;
    cloud.style.left = cloudx + "px";
    if(cloudx > window.innerWidth)
    {
        startCloud();
    }
}
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getUTCHours();
if (time < 2 || time > 16)
{
    //if day time
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "#81bcff";
    document.getElementById("sunmoonimg").src = "sun.png";
}
if (time >= 2 && time <= 16)
{
    //if night time
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "#243447";
    document.getElementById("sunmoonimg").src = "moon.png";
}
```

Here is a link to my site with a demo:
http://www.keirp.com/stopit

Comment: No problems on my motorola droid (surprisingly). Have you tried creating a wrapper div that has `overflow:hidden;` as opposed to putting that on the body? That has been a problem for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

While many mobile browsers claim to be HTML 5 compliant, as of this posting there are many known issues with the actual support of some style properties such as `overflow`.

See these articles for more on this:

- Good list of browser mobile support - http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html
- specifically when considering jquery mobile - http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/touchoverflow.html
- this one is a bit older but discusses iphone specific issues - http://blog.bahrenburgs.com/2009/11/div-overflow-and-iphone-browsing.html
- SO post on iOS discrepancies in Safari - [List of known "Safari on iPad" differences over "Desktop Safari"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006647/list-of-known-safari-on-ipad-differences-over-desktop-safari)
- great post on viewport meta tag - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

That last one might be the key to your answer.

Hope this helps!