# Is there any way to style optgroup using CSS on the iPad?

Tags: html, css, ipad

Is there any way to style the HTML element 'optgroup' using CSS? It's specifically important the style appears on the mobile iOS browser for iPad.

The HTML is:

```
 <optgroup label="Great Britain">
    <option value="EUROPE_ENGLAND">England</option>
    <option value="EUROPE_SCOTLAND">Scotland</option>
    <option value="EUROPE_WALES">Wales</option>
 </optgroup>
```

And the CSS is:

```
optgroup {
  color: red;
}
```

I'm not even sure it's possible to style the iPad's optgroup by the way.

Comment: It is supported on safari http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Comment: @AzzyDude what's the issue exactly? Did you try styling but it didn't get rendered? If so, please provide the relevant HTML/CSS.

Comment: @EricFrick What about mobile safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do it. iPad Safari takes full control of styling select lists' internal contents. Here's a reference for verification: [little link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006647/list-of-known-safari-on-ipad-differences-over-desktop-safari).

One way to achieve this this would be to simulate the dropdown/select menu using JavaScript. It's not very preferable, but if you require to change the default styling, then I'm afraid it's the only way to go; here's a demo that should give you an idea on how to do the simulation: [another little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/963ax/).

Answer (score 0):

You can just style it through css:

```
 optgroup {
  font-style: italic;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9VzV6/

You can also add a class/ID to each optgroup tag if required.

Comment: Did you test this on an iPad? I don't have one, which is why I asked. I'm not entirely sure how select boxes are drawn on an iPad.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't render on iPad. The default look is light grey and italic. Can't seem to change it.