# Styling the first option of a <select> input on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, css, select

I'm trying to style a `select` input on iOS. The first option or initial state should have smaller font-size but not the rest of the options.

I have the following html structure:

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option selected="" value="Navigation">Navigation</option>
    <option value="some-link">Whatever</option>
    <option value="some-link">Another option</option>
    <option value="some-link">Why</option>
    <option value="some-link">What</option>
</select>
```

My CSS for it looks like this:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    font-family: 'Custom-Font', sans-serif;
    font-size:.5em
    line-height:1.8em; // optical center
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #333;
    border: none;
    padding: 6px 10px 4px 10px;
}

.dropdown {
    background-image: url(img/assets.svg);
    background-position: right 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:-1.5em;

    option:not(:first-of-type) {
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
}
```

The `<select>` menu looks exactly like I want it to look. It says "Navigation" inside a light-gray box with a rather small font-size.

However when clicking/tapping the `select` on my iphone the native UI view of iOS shows all options also in a very small font-size.

How can I just make the `selected` option (or the box itself) use the custom formatting but not the options. I want my options to have a "normal" readable font-size.

Any ideas on that? I tried with `option:not(:first-of-type)` and increase the font-size but no effect!

Comment: How did you solve this issue @matt?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do it. **iOS Safari** takes full control of styling `select` lists' internal contents. Here's a reference for verification: [little link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006647/list-of-known-safari-on-ipad-differences-over-desktop-safari).

One way to achieve this this would be to simulate the dropdown/select menu using JavaScript.

It's not very preferable, but if you *absolutely* require to change the default styling, then I'm afraid it's the only way to go; here's a demo that should give you an idea on how to do the simulation: [another little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/963ax/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this 100% worked for me

```
select { 
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. I wished it showed the drop down select arrow but... I'll take it. Thanks.

Comment: This solution does not work on iOS devices - per the original post.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - I had a transparent `<select>` dropdown with a border radius when closed. On iOS (I'm not sure about android, I didn't test it) the default grey box for the `<select>` would appear inside of my custom border which was unappealing and unwanted.

To get rid of the inner grey box I used the following CSS:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

And further more - pertaining to this OP's topic. Bootstrap offers a convenient solution with great documentation to enable custom dropdowns with Javascript. [Check it out here.](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)