# Is there a way to use a standard select menu on an iphone?

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, html

I'm making a mobile website. I'm using HTML5, Wordpress, and jquery among other things.  I am using a jquery plugin called Easy Drop Down Menu to style a standard html select menu.  When the menu is clicked on the iphone it shows the list of possibilities in a Flip wheel.  We don't like the Flip wheel.  We would rather see our styled drop down menu.

Is there a way to bypass the iPhone Flip Wheel?

Is there a way to tell Safari in iOS to not use the Flip Wheel rolodex thing but show the drop down menu like it would show on the desktop.

I don't have this problem with Windows Phone.  It shows the styled select menu options.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12651516/754705) from 2012. Maybe something has changed since then, but I fear not.

Comment: Thanks michael.  This is what i was afraid of.