# Worklight: How to change dropdown text size for iOS version 8.0 and above?

Tags: ios8, ibm-mobilefirst, ios8.1

I have a dropdown in my WL application which looks fine in android and iOS<7. But for iOS versions 8.0 and above the dropdown text looks bigger and the whole text doesn't fit in.

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand why this relates to Worklight/MobileFirst.

If you are developing a hybrid app, then check the CSS in an iOS simulator... if it's a native app, then check the UI values...

Comment: yes its hybrid app... and developing on windows.. so no iOS simulator... its a sample app that I am trying!!

Comment: @Aditi, not possibe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651507/styling-a-select-input-for-ios-first-option-or-initial-state-should-have-smal