# mobile safari: change background color of picker view (select)

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

Mobile Safari uses a `UIPickerView` for `<select>` elements - I'd like to change the background color of it with CSS. As you can see in the screen shot below, it's very hard to read. What you are looking at is the State `<select>` form element. Changing the text color or background color of the `<select>` element itself doesn't fix the problem.

I thought it was related to a parent element's or its own background color - but I went up the line and changed every ancestor element's background color to white and the problem persisted. Is there a prefixed style or trick to making this GUI legible? Or maybe it's just a bug.

EDIT: The gray behind the `UIPickerView` is filled in by mobile Safari, since the select is almost at the bottom of the page. Mobile Safari vertically centers the select above the `UIPickerView` and fills in the extra space below the page with the gray. The question is, how does it determine to use that dark gray? I've tried changing the body text color, and background-color of every other element on the page to no avail.

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating this... A couple of questions:

1. Does the <select> have any additional attributes, such as required
2. Do you have a link or jsfiddle example with the rest of the code?

Comment: This is an old project... it would take me a while to dig it up. FWIW, this was a phonegap project.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do it. **iOS Safari** takes full control of styling `select` lists' internal contents. Here's a reference for verification: [little link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006647/list-of-known-safari-on-ipad-differences-over-desktop-safari).

One way to achieve this this would be to simulate the dropdown/select menu using JavaScript.

It's not very preferable, but if you *absolutely* require to change the default styling, then I'm afraid it's the only way to go; here's a demo that should give you an idea on how to do the simulation: [another little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/963ax/).