# How to reverse text overlay and image of the masonry grid?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, grid, masonry

My masonry grid (the following code) displays an image, when I hover it, it shows text 'MyPost2'.

```
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-portfolio elementor-grid elementor-posts-container elementor-has-item-ratio">
        <article class="elementor-portfolio-item elementor-post post-6346 project type-project status-publish hentry elementor-active" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
        <a class="elementor-post__thumbnail__link" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/project/MyPost2/">
            <div class="elementor-portfolio-item__img elementor-post__thumbnail">
                    </div>
            <div class="elementor-portfolio-item__overlay">
            <h3 class="elementor-portfolio-item__title">MyPost2</h3></div>
        </a>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question : Is there any method to reverse them, so it displays text, when I hover it, it shows an image?

Thank you.

Comment: Please put up example code to show what you have already. See [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007046/mobile-safari-change-background-color-of-picker-view-select

Comment: Hi Haworth：I'm sorry, my bad. I updated my current grid. Thank you for your help.